# using matches of regex in vi global substitution

Tags: regular-expression, vi

I am trying to edit a text file using `vi` where I want to replace the matches of `[a-z]`,`[A-Z]` with:

```
{matching value of [a-z]}{a space instead of a comma}{matching value of [A-Z]}.
```

For example: `Bourbon,Glazed,Turkey,`

would be replaced with: `Bourbon Glazed Turkey,`

I was thinking it might be using grouping & back referencing? But I have not figured that out yet.

Comment: I just figured it out. Came back to answer my own question, but you two beat me to te same answer I came up with! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The `vi` command `%s/\([a-z]\),\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g` will change

```
y,S
T,d
5,e
```

into

```
y S
T,d
5,e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'Bourbon,Glazed,Turkey,' | sed 's/\([a-z]\),\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g'
Bourbon Glazed Turkey,
$
```

So in `vi` it's the same:

```
:%s/\([a-z]\),\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g
```